# Start date and end date datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

I have input date that contains start date and end date to filter period. I want to make start date is todays date and the end date is same with start date or one day after start date. The condition is if I choose start date in 01-04-2017 I just can choose 01-04-2017 or date after that in end date input.

This is what I have been done but still doesn't give best answer.

```
<div class="col-md-4">
   <div class="input-group input-daterange">
        <input type="text" name="from_date_alt" id="from_date_alt" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="Start date" value="">
        <span class="input-group-addon">to</span>
        <input type="text" name="to_date_alt" id="to_date_alt" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="End date" value="">
   </div>
</div>
```

This is the script.

```
var nowDate = new Date();
var today = new Date(nowDate.getFullYear(), nowDate.getMonth(), nowDate.getDate(), 0, 0, 0, 0);

$(".datepicker").datepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
    startDate: today,
    autoclose: true
});
```

How could I to do that ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", new Date(2017, 3 - 1, 31));
  } );
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  } );
  </script>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

I do not understand, something like this?